# Python: how to avoid a loop that calls two functions?

Tags: python, loops, apply

I downloaded a geottif image that contains the population in Haiti from the [worldpop.org](https://www.worldpop.org/).

The image can be downloaded from [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1D3m-UQZ_pOaLBKa3HTtk32h4BhwiTcey/view?usp=sharing)

```
from osgeo import gdal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm

fileO = 'HTI_ppp_v2b_2015_UNadj_32618.tif'
geo = gdal.Open(fileO)
topo = geo.ReadAsArray()
i, j = np.where(topo>0)
topo = topo[min(i):max(i)+1, min(j):max(j)+1]
topo[topo<0] = np.nan

fig = plt.figure(frameon=False)
plt.imshow(topo, cmap=cm.BrBG_r)
plt.axis('off')
cbar = plt.colorbar(shrink=0.75)
cbar.set_label('meters')
plt.show()
```

[image]

I would like to assign each value to a coordinate, i.e. the centroid coordinates of the pixel and have a dataframe like the following

```
df_coord:
    X_centr   Y_centr   Pop
0   650000    2050000   54   
1   556000    2250000   NaN
```

This what I am doing but the process takes too much time.

```
import affine
import pandas as pd


def retrieve_pixel_value(geo_coord, data_source):
    """Return floating-point value that corresponds to given point."""
    x, y = geo_coord[0], geo_coord[1]
    forward_transform =  \
        affine.Affine.from_gdal(*data_source.GetGeoTransform())
    reverse_transform = ~forward_transform
    px, py = reverse_transform * (x, y)
    px, py = int(px + 0.5), int(py + 0.5)
    pixel_coord = px, py

    data_array = np.array(data_source.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray())
    return data_array[pixel_coord[0]][pixel_coord[1]]
def pixel2coord(col, row):
    """Returns global coordinates to pixel center using base-0 raster index"""
    xp = a * col + b * row + a * 0.5 + b * 0.5 + c
    yp = d * col + e * row + d * 0.5 + e * 0.5 + f
    return(xp, yp)

fileO = 'HTI_ppp_v2b_2015_UNadj_32618.tif'
geo = gdal.Open(fileO)
topo = geo.ReadAsArray()
i, j = np.where(topo>0)
topo = topo[min(i):max(i)+1, min(j):max(j)+1]

x_coord = []
y_coord = []
val = []
for idx in range(0,len(i)):
    ii = i[idx]
    jj = j[idx]
    coords = pixel2coord(ii, jj)  ## find coordinates of the pixel
    x_coord.append(coords[0])      
    y_coord.append(coords[1])
    pop = retrieve_pixel_value(coords, geo) ## retrieve pixel value at given coordinates - coords
    val.append(pop)

import pandas as pd
df_coord = pd.DataFrame()
df_coord['X_coord'] = ii
df_coord['Y_coord'] = jj
df_coord['Pop'] = val
```

Is it possible to do the same without doing the loop?

Comment: What is the length of i ? Maybe you can reduce the number of loop by using less precise values. What if you use not the value of one pixel but by square of 10 pixel for exemple ?

Comment: @BaptisteGavalda The length of `i` is `3343491`. I can also do that but I would like to try to see if can reduce this loop first. But of course any suggestions are more than welcome

Comment: @BaptisteGavalda how would you transform it?

Comment: I'm not sure if it is a good idea, but 2 things : is it possible to fill i and j by package or second in your loop could you increment not but 1 but for exemple by 10 to make average of the ten points and so decrease the number of loop